# Can't install mysqldump on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

Another technician recently reinstalled our mysql on our LAMP-server and now I can't use mysqldump anymore.

```
# mysqldump
The program 'mysqldump' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install mysql-client-5.5
```

So I do that:

```
apt-get install mysql-client-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 percona-server-server-5.5 : Depends: percona-server-client-5.5 (>= 1:5.5.36-rel34.2-648.precise) but     it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Ok I do that:

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libterm-readkey-perl mysql-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  percona-server-client-5.5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  percona-server-client-5.5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,371 kB of archives.
After this operation, 30.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

This kinda sounds like it's gonna remove some mysql stuff and install another sort of database, but ok "Y".

```
(Reading database ... 67693 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking percona-server-client-5.5 (from .../percona-server-client-5.5_1%3a5.5.36-rel34.2-    648.precise_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/percona-server-client-5.5_1%3a5.5.36-rel34.2-    648.precise_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysqlcheck', which is also in package mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.35-    0ubuntu0.12.04.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/percona-server-client-5.5_1%3a5.5.36-rel34.2-648.precise_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone see what's going on here?
Is there maybe a way to manually install mysqldump?
Or maybe even another way of making dump-files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percona is a MySQL fork/alternative and you have repos configured and enabled for it. You have 2 choices:

1) Remove anything related to Percona, including the repos and install MySQL.

2) Rmove anything related to MySQL and install Percona. Maybe clear the apt cache and do an apt-get update to try and fix the issue you have at your last command.

Comment: Thank you. How can you tell that Percona is installed?
I checked ps and it doesn't seem like I'm running anything Percona.
What do you think has happened, why do I have Percona stuff on the server and why didn't mysqldump get installed? Shouldn't that come with the apt package automatically?